# Delete object in list based on field value Vue.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I have an array of objects and I want to delete objects is one of the properties are true. For instance,

```
data(){
  return{
      entries : [
                 {
                name : "name here",
                age : 20,
                school:"UTK",
                isSelected : false
          },{
                name : "name here",
                age : 20,
                school:"UTK",
                isSelected : false
          },{
                name : "name here",
                age : 20,
                school:"UTK",
                isSelected : false
          }
       ]
  }
{
```

When the user clicks a button, I call a function in my methods block. I need the function to delete all objects that has the property "isSelected" set to true.

Any help is appreciated!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The method should contain the following code that filters the items with `isSelected:true` and remove them :

```
this.entries=this.entries.filter(entry=>!entry.isSelected)
```

Comment: why did i get a down vote? if there's something went wrong with my answer you could comment

Answer (score 2):

in a function:

```
this.entries = this.entries.filter(e=> e.isSelected == true);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use [filter()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) inside the entries object:

```
data(){
  return{
      entries : [
                 {
                name : "name here",
                age : 20,
                school:"UTK",
                isSelected : false
          },{
                name : "name here",
                age : 20,
                school:"UTK",
                isSelected : false
          },{
                name : "name here",
                age : 20,
                school:"UTK",
                isSelected : false
          }
       ].filter(e=>e.isSelected!=true)
  }
  
}
```